# converting MFC desktop application GUI in java

Tags: java, c++, swing, mfc, code-conversion

I have a MFC based desktop application. Application is whole written in MFC so it is not cross platform compatible Hence i need to make it cross compatible. I thought to convert GUI part into java (swing) for cross compatibility and make dll or .so file by separating and wrapping pure cpp logic and access it through JNI/JNA so can any one help me how to separate gui part and logic in MFC based application so that i can make GUI in the java ? I don`t have deeper knowledge in MFC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MFC based applications do not necessarily have a clean separation between the GUI and the program logic. MFC arranges calls into the functions on C++ classes, and those classes can contain not only GUI handling but all of the application logic. People don't always write MFC apps with a crystal ball telling them that someone will want the GUI parts in Java while keeping the rest.

Sorry, your question is not really of the kind for which you can get specific in this kind of forum which will resolve the challenge you are facing. You have to study the MFC app from the inside and out, take it apart and do the best you can. It could take quite a bit of effort and could end up in a total rewrite (with the logic ending up in Java also).

Stack Overflow works best when you have something concrete, like an example piece of code which is failing or needs to be transformed into doing something else, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I know It could take quite a bit of effort i had posted this question to just get idea if any mfc programmer can give some idea to startup(The first step ) the conversion

Comment: First step: get really familiar with the MFC app. Explore every feature as a user; read every shred of available documentation, study the source code. Build it in Visual Studio, single step into functions, etc.  If the application log is not separated from the GUI, it might not be a good idea to actually work that into the MFC version first. I.e transform the MFC program into one which still works (as far as executing any of its test cases), but has a better separation. Then the program can maybe "spin off" the application logic with greater ease.